# how to pass checkbox data to another activity

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

How to pass checkbox data from one activity to another? If the checkbox is checked/selected, it will pass data in a form of String from first activity to second activity. The second activity will get the String and set the text on _Job_fx, but why does other checkbox Strings appear when the checkbox wasn't check? My data bypass my condition and set text on _Job_fx. How to fix this?

first activity:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Add_job_fx", MODE_PRIVATE);

_electric_item01 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item01);
checkbox(_electric_item01);
_electric_item02 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item02);
checkbox(_electric_item02);
_electric_item03 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item03);
checkbox(_electric_item03);
_electric_item04 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item04);
checkbox(_electric_item04);

    private void checkbox(final CheckBox check) {

        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (check.isSelected()) {
                    //edit shared preference (put data)
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    //put data in shared preference
                    editor.putString(check.getText().toString(), check.getText().toString());
                    //apply changes to shared preference
                    editor.apply();
                }
                else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.remove(check.getText().toString());
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

second activity:

```
//shared preferences (Name, Mode)
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Add_job_fx", MODE_PRIVATE);
//get data from shared preference
s_electric_item01 = sharedPreferences.getString("Change lightbulb", "");
s_electric_item02 = sharedPreferences.getString("Change starter", "");
s_electric_item03 = sharedPreferences.getString("Change light set", "");
s_electric_item04 = sharedPreferences.getString("Change fan + regulator", "");
//pass data to container for view 
_Job_fx.setText("Job: " + s_electric_item01 +"\n"+ s_electric_item02 + "\n"+ s_electric_item03);
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to combine `remove()` and `clear()` together?

Comment: Also I am looking at documentation right now and if calling `apply()` while using `putString()` or any other "put" is okay then while using `remove()` and `clear()` there is only said about combining it with `commit()`. [remove() docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#remove(java.lang.String)) [clear() docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#clear())

Comment: Oh I got mad and put 2 restrictions to remove the data from sharedpreference. It doesn't work...I don't know what is causing my first activity to bypass my if statement and pass data to second activity even though my checkbox wasn't selected.

Comment: I thought so, but have you tried with `commit()` instead of `apply()`? Only for removing data.

Comment: Tried, nope doesn't work.

Comment: Try do do it all inside `OnCheckedChangeListener()`. It is proper way to manage check boxes state changes.

Comment: It ended up crashing upon selecting/checking checkbox, but the second activity still receive the String and set previous text bypassing the first activity.

Comment: Is there a better way to pass data from one activity to another activity only when a checkbox is checked?

Comment: You are talking about passing data but it only is true or false for checkboxes. I wonder why you save the state in shared preferences where you can use putExtra() in the intent that starts the second activity. Further if you want to stay with shared preferences and remove does not work you could just change "true"to "false".

Comment: You only need one line in onClick:                    `editor.putString(check.getText().toString(), check.isChecked()? "true": "false");` Then save . You use isSelected() but isnt there an isChecked()?

Comment: Alright, I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, the thing about sharedpreferences is that it automatically saves data even if the application shuts down. So by default every time I go to the second activity after the first try, it saves the previous String to `_Job_fx.setText`. The solution is just set the default empty by removing the previous String.

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Add_job_fx", MODE_PRIVATE);

_electric_item01 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item01);
checkbox(_electric_item01);
_electric_item02 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item02);
checkbox(_electric_item02);
_electric_item03 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item03);
checkbox(_electric_item03);
_electric_item04 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.electric_item04);
checkbox(_electric_item04);

private void checkbox(final CheckBox check) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove(check.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (check.isChecked()) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(check.getText().toString(), check.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();
                } else if (!check.isChecked()) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.remove(check.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to firstly check if the checkbox is checked or not , if checked
returns true , and accordingly get your checkbox values and use it in
Sharedpreferences

```
 private void checkbox(final CheckBox check) {

          SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
        getSharedPreferences("Add_job_fx", MODE_PRIVATE); //add this line here 
        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
             CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean 
                isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) { // here check if the checkbox is checked 
                    // or not if yes then retreive the value and push it into 
                    // Sharedpreferences

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("put a key here ",
                            check.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();
                }
                else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.remove("put your key to remove from SP , the same key 
                     as 
                            above");
                            editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: The problem still remains. Isn't the code same as mine?

Comment: what is your exact problem , i couldn't get it well

Comment: For some reason the first activity sharedpreference bypass the if statement and pass String to second activity. So even my checkbox isn't selected/check, the second activity still receives the String causing ```Job_fx.setText("Job: " + s_electric_item01 +"\n"+ s_electric_item02 + "\n"+ s_electric_item03);``` to display unchecked checkbox

Comment: i guess you need to use OnCheckedChangeListener instead of clicklistener , check my code , i editted it

Comment: I used your code and the problem is the same. Nothing change.

Comment: does it still bypass the if statement ?

Comment: Surprisingly yes, it bypass the if statement.

Comment: can you show the code of this function private void checkbox(final CheckBox check) , the code from where you pass the checkbox

Comment: Actually this is a full code, there is nothing else.

Comment: then from where you re getting this checkbox ! final CheckBox check

Comment: do you have have a checkbox in your xml layout !

Comment: the xml u requested, is too long in the comment. So I place it as answer below.

Comment: put this line inside the checkbox function , why are you putting it out ? check my editted answer

Comment: I tried and it is still the same, nothing change. I didn't put in because I have coded on the first line.